# Image Disappears when Creating CGContext Line

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm creating a simple Mini-Golf game app on Xcode using Objective-C. I added a guide line where if the user touches the ball and swipes their finger, a line would show the direction of where the ball moves. I was able to create the line, but the image(contextImage) that I connected with disappears when I swipe the screen. How would I make it so that the image does not disappear?

Here is my touchesMoved code:

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
     UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
     movePoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];

     if (CGRectContainsPoint([ball frame], firstPoint)) {
          UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
          CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
          CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 1);
          CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor colorWithRed:1.0f green:1.0f blue:1.0 alpha:1.0] CGColor]);
          CGContextMoveToPoint(context, ball.center.x, ball.center.y);
          CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, movePoint.x, movePoint.y);
          CGContextStrokePath(context);

          self.contextImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
          UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
     }
}
```